# How to read himawari-8 header?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system

I have Himawari-8 data (.nc files) 
but I want to know the information such as projection, calibration, data acquisition,
I got this data from Meteorology agency in my country and I thought if the data has been modified so the original header is replaced with the new one (after the processing)
How do i know or read the original header?

Comment: Do you have netcdf tools? Start with ncdump -h filename.nc  at the console.

Comment: Have you tried gdalinfo?. Possibly related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188500/georeferencing-himawari-8-in-gdal-or-other

Comment: I do but , the meteorology agency said if the data is not a pure netcdf file but those datas were developed  based on hdf file. so when I tried with ncdump , there is a message " MTS_IR_0000 is not a netcdf file" then I tried with panoply but the information wasn't complete.

Do you have the information or original header from Himawari-8 that contain information such as projection, calibration, geometric correction? If you do , please contact me more on my e-mail. (fajar.dewangga@gmail.com)
I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have only the information I gave in my answer. I have not registered to obtain original Himawari files. http://www.data.jma.go.jp/mscweb/en/himawari89/space_segment/spsg_sample.html might be helpful for you.